# Repository could not be found Spring R2DBC

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

In my code, I ran into this weird issue where one of my repositories is not being recognized in my controller and throwing this error during startup.

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.pack.controller.ModulesController required a bean of type 'com.test.pack.repository.ModuleRepository' that could not be found.

This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/modules")
class ModulesController(private val moduleRepository: ModuleRepository) {
    @GetMapping
    suspend fun getAllModules(): = Response(moduleRepository.findAllPurchasableModule().toList())
}
```

This is my repository

```
interface ModuleRepository: Repository<Module, Int> {
    suspend fun getByAccountId(accountId: Long): Flow<Module>
    suspend fun findAllPurchasableModule(): Flow<Module>
}
```

and `impl`

```
class ModuleRepositoryImpl(private val databaseClient: DatabaseClient) : ModuleRepository {

    override suspend fun getByAccountId(accountId: Long): Flow<Module> {

        return databaseClient.execute("SELECT * FROM mod WHERE actid = :acct").bind("accountId", acct).asType<Module>().fetch().flow()
    }

    override suspend fun findAllPurchasableModule(): Flow<Module> {

        return databaseClient.execute("SELECT * FROM modules").asType<Module>().fetch().flow()
    }
}
```

and this is my folder structure

```
com
    test
        pack
            controller
                ModulesController
            repository
                ModuleRepository
                UserRepository
                impl
                    ModuleRepositoryImpl
                    UserRepositoryImpl
```

and I am doing the exact same for the `User` repository as well and it is working. However, if I put `@Repository("moduleRepository")` on top of `impl` class then it works. But I do not understand what is special about this ModuleRepository that same concept as others are not working for this one.

Comment: Show us your folder structure

Comment: Have you added @Repository annotation above the repository class?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I added folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you **should always** use the @Repository and other annotations like @Component, @Service etc for Spring to easily detect during classpath scanning and register it in the Application context as a bean.

The reason why the User Repository is working, might be because (excluding the  moduleRepository ) it's the only Repository type bean present in your code currently.

Comment: Still getting the same error while using @Repository